# How to install Ubuntu Touch 16.04 on Nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I followed the steps on https://devices.ubports.com/#/hammerhead to install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 5, and I got Ubuntu 15.04. How do I get 16.04?

Note that when installing the system per above instructions, the GUI update checker (yes, attempted before putting the file system in read-write mode) does not find one.

Comment: No, the answer that there should be a full-image update available OTA doesn't apply here, because when using the touch GUI to check for one (before putting the file system in read-write mode), there isn't one.

Comment: any update here ? i am also trying to install it on nexus 5 - i cant see how to proceed after installing UBPorts ?

Comment: I gave up on pursuing this. Instead, I found that Scaleway's cloud offerings and Crouton on Samsung Chromebook 2 suit my armv7 and aarch64 development needs better.

Comment: The UBports community has announced the first release candidate of their long-awaited Ubuntu Touch OTA-4 update. This update will be released for all previously supported devices. Ubuntu Touch OTA-4 is based on Ubuntu 16.04 which will be supported for another 3 years instead of the antiquated Ubuntu 15.04. More details on the Ubuntu Touch OTA-4 release candidate are available at [UBports.com](https://ubports.com/blog/ubports-blog-1/post/ubuntu-touch-rc-ota-4-148).

Comment: You simply need to select one of the 16.04 channels in the ubports installer. There were no usable 16.04 based images when this question was asked, however.